# Disable checkbox based on value by jquery handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, php, handlebars.js

I have a HTML `table` that includes a `checkbox` with multiple selection (`handlebar`). I have set the value of `{{status}}` which is `Yes` and `No`.

**How can I disable `{{status}}` `checkbox` when the value is equal to `No(Function)`?**

```
{{#invoices}}
    <tr>
        <td><input name="select_option" id="{{status}} "value="{{open_amount}}" type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{company_code}}</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{invoice_no}}</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{invoice_type}}</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{invoice_date}}</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{due_date}}</td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><font color="{{color}}">{{status}}</font></td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{open_amount}}</td>
    </tr>{{/invoices}}
```

```js
{{#invoices}}
function disable(){
 if(document.getElementById('{{status}}') == 'Pending Process'){
    document.getElementById('select_option').disabled = true;
 }else{
    document.getElementById('select_option').disabled = false;
 }
}
{{/invoices}}
```

Its that work ?

Comment: Could you add custom helpers to handlebars ?

Comment: @ChristopheThiry edited what i doing right now

Comment: Your second version won't work because status is not an ID it is a string containing the value you want to test.

Comment: so any solution by using this way ?

Comment: It's hard to answer without better understanding of what you want to achieve. There is probably a solution but not with the elements that you want to use right now. Also there is a mistake in the JS because you set the disabled to true in any case.

Comment: In this case, i wan to disable the checkbox when {{status}} value is 'Pending Process'. I using PHP(sqlquery) to call the value

Comment: Try to replace the id='{{status}}' by a class because id is something that have to be unique on your page. So class="{{#test status 'eq' 'Pending Process'}}toDisable{{/test}}". And then if you're using jquery you can add a selector $(".toDisable").each(function () ...)  with a disable in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually to test values I use a custom helper :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
    var doDisplay = false;
    var items = (""+rvalue).split("|");
    var arrayLength = items.length;
    for (var i = 0; (i < arrayLength); i++) {
        if (operator == "eq") {
            if (lvalue == items[i]) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "ne") {
            if (lvalue != items[i]) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "gt") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) > parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "lt") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) < parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }else if (operator == "le") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) <= parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }else if (operator == "ge") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) >= parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (doDisplay) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});
```

You can use it like that :

```
<td><input name="select_option" value="{{open_amount}}" type="checkbox" {{#test status 'eq' 'No(Function)'}}
   disabled
{{/test}}/></td>
```

Comment: You're welcome it is too bad that handlebar doesn't ship with such helper.

Comment: Can i use JS function to present helper ?

Comment: What do you mean by "present" ? The helper will display whatever you want if you want to display a JS function it will also work.

Answer (score 1):

you can us the binding of attribute 'disabled'.

```
<td><input name="select_option" {{status==='No'?'disabled':''}} value="{{open_amount}}" type="checkbox"/></td>
```